# Apache Nifi fresh install: No users.xml and authorizations.xml

Tags: apache-nifi

Did a fresh install of Apache Nifi using unofficial Docker for Nifi (https://hub.docker.com/r/apache/nifi/). No users.xml and authorizations.xml found in conf directory. FYI, the conf directory has configuration files like nifi.properties, authorizers.xml, login-identity-providers.xml etc.

The Nifi menu does not show all menu options for anonymous login, like Users menu etc.

How do I enable (i.e make viewable) all the menu options in Nifi UI?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you install Apache NiFi (building from source or downloading the binaries), the `users.xml` and `authorizations.xml` files will not exist at first. When the application is started for the first time, the `authorizers.xml` file is read and processed, and these files are generated from the configured `UserGroupProvider` and `AccessPolicyProvider`.

If you do not choose to secure NiFi using HTTPS, all access is anonymous, and no user accounts are created.

If you choose to secure it, you will have the capability to configure and manage users, groups, and permissions within the NiFi UI.

It is unclear from your question which menu options you expect to see in the global menu when accessing the application as an anonymous user. Please clarify the question or refer to [NiFi Admin Guide -- Multi-Tenant Authorization](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/administration-guide.html#multi-tenant-authorization) for further details.

Comment: [@Andy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/70465/andy) - Appreciate your answer and pointers. I checked the authorizers.xml and found that AccessPolicyProvider uses {User Group Provider = file-user-group-provider} and {Authorizations File = ./conf/authorizations.xml}. UserGroupProvider uses {identifier = file-user-group-provider} and {Users File = ./conf/users.xml}. Restart of Nifi did not create the users.xml and authorizations.xml. I am interesting in Users menu which are not visible for me.

Comment: If you stop the application, delete the `users.xml` and `authorizations.xml` files in the `$NIFI_HOME/conf/` directory, and populate an `Initial Admin Identity` value (something like `CN=alopresto, OU=NiFi`) in `authorizers.xml` (two places), and then restart the application, the `users.xml` and `authorizations.xml` files will be generated.

**Please note this only happens if you have [followed the steps to secure NiFi with TLS / HTTPS](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/administration-guide.html#security-configuration).** Unsecured NiFi instances do not have the concept of users.